# Speeding up Oracle database interface in Qt (QOCI)

Tags: c++, database, oracle, qt

I have a project that involves integrating an Oracle database into a Qt desktop app. Since Qt has a really easy to use interface for database interaction, I compiled the QOCI driver to support Oracle connections.

Everything works fine, but the processing time for queries is incredibly slow. How can I improve performance?

My code for processing an arbitrary query looks like this:

```
QList< QList<QString> > DBWrapper::executeQuery(QString const& queryString)
{
    QList< QList<QString> > results;
    if (_db.isOpen()) {
        QSqlQuery qry(queryString);
        if(qry.exec()) {
            while(qry.next()) {
                QList<QString> row;
                results.append(row);
                for(int i = 0; i < qry.record().count(); ++i) {
                    results.last().append(qry.value(i).toString());
                }
            }
        } else {
            qDebug() << queryString;
            qDebug() << "FAILURE: cannot handle query.";
            qDebug() << "  > " << qry.lastError();
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Error Opening Database = " << _db.lastError();
    }

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were some ressources describing the same issue with other DBMS in Qt. All of them were suggesting to add `qry.setForwardOnly(true)` and `qry.prepare(queryString);` to the query setup.

Although, that seems like good style reading the Qt documentation, it barely got me any improvement. Debugging the code I ran some speed tests, reducing everything only to measure the run time of the QSql stuff.

```
//...
QSqlQuery qry(queryString);
qry.setForwardOnly(true);
qry.prepare(queryString);

QElapsedTimer timer;
timer.start();
if(qry.exec()) {
    qDebug() << "time to execute query: " << timer.elapsed() << "ms";
    timer.start();
    while(qry.next()) {
         // don't do anything here
    }
    qDebug() << "time to iterate through query results: " << timer.elapsed() << "ms";
}
```

Turns out, that executing the query was done in less than 50 ms while iterating over the results took about 3000 ms, with only 100 elements in the result of my SELECT statement.

The solution was hard to find, but seems fairly straight forward. When setting up the database connection you can define connection options that are specific for the type of DBMS you are working with. OCI defines `OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS`, which defaults to 1. Setting a higher value rapidly increases iteration speed.

```
_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI");
_db.setHostName(host);
_db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
_db.setPort(port);
_db.setUserName(user);
_db.setPassword(pwd);

_db.setConnectOptions("OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS=1000");

_db.open();
```

Please, somebody correct me if I am wrong, but I am guessing each select query will cache a maximum amount of rows in an underlying storage structure in Qt. I believe this number to be equal to the value of `OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS`. Since `qry.value(...)` only points to one row (QSqlRecord), I am assuming that `OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS = 1` will mean that on each `qry.next()` the database will somehow be queried again internally to move this cursor. This would totally destroy performance as it did for me.

I hope this post will be found by somebody who is as desperate as I was facing this issue.

Comment: Just instinct but I'd say it's all the round trips between the client and the db server that was killing your performance - increasing the rows fetched per trip to 1000 sounds like the right path to go down. c.f. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci04sql.htm#i429698

Comment: This is correct. Database server roundtrips have real latency that quickly adds up. Furthermore, since database drivers have blocking interfaces, none of the queries should be running on the main thread. You should use a dedicated thread, or send the request off to the thread pool for execution, with the proviso that only one thread can use the database connection at any time.

Comment: I was wondering, is there a reason for having such a low default value for `OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS`? I mean, I can see how you would want to limit the number of prefetch rows on a large query, to reduce memory overhead. But, Unless I only `SELECT` single elements, `OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS` = 1 would always cause roundtrips, right?